# Foundation.Date does not conform to Sendable. Now what?

Tags: swift, sendable

The following presents a warning in Xcode 14 complete concurrency checking mode.

```
struct Article: Sendable {
    let title: String
    let date: Date // non sendable type warning
}
```

This warning will become an error in Swift 6.

How do we handle this?

Comment: I would expect this warning to be fixed before we get Swift 6 so I am not going to do anything about it in my code.

Comment: you could try making Date Sendable, using `extension Date: Sendable {}`

Comment: Also noticed in the Swift forum some time ago: https://forums.swift.org/t/foundation-date-type-not-sendable/55160

Answer (score 0):

The sendable attribute only applies to function types, so we can convert the property to that type instead.

```
struct Article: Sendable {
    let title: String
    let date: @Sendable () -> Date
}
```